# React safelySetState - Anti pattern or good practice?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, asynchronous

I was recently met with the

> "Can only update a mounted or mounting component."

error message when I tried setting the state after a asynchronous fetch call was made. It occurred because the component was unmounted before the http response got back.

Then I started googling, and found a solution to the problem.

What if a variable was holding the "mounted"-state, and every time I wanted to update the state, I would just check the variable? Like a safelySetState() function?

Here is an example:

```
componentDidMount = () => {
  this._mounted = true;
}

componentWillUnmount = () => {
  this._mounted = false; 
}

safelySetState = (obj) => {
  if(this._mounted)
    this.setState(obj);
}
```

Then, every time I wanted to update the state, I would just use the this.safelySetState() function instead.

So my question is: **Why should I not do this? Why isn't this already default in React?**

Comment: to add to the answer @andriusain provided, what happens when you call `safelySetState()` and it doesn't set the state?  You are creating other problems by trying to "bypass" an error, when your app suddenly does something unexpected because it *thought* that a state was set that in fact was not.

Answer (score 0):

My guess for it not being  default in React is that it is out of their scope. It would not have been great on their part to silently do nothing if the state cannot be set. Rather it is logical they throw an error so they let you know it cannot be done and leave how you want to handle that up to you.

Also I would be wary of always using your function for the same reasons... it can make debugging your app a little hard and obscure... probably you should implement it externally, not as a function... but inline with the rest of the code and just for the edge cases that really need it... or at the very least log a warning when the component is not available